# How to move indexpath.row to a new view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to move this `indexPath.row` to the view controller `pageView`

## So this is what I have tried:

---

#### First off getting the indexPath row from the corresponding button

```
[cell.nav addTarget:self action:@selector(naviguate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.nav.tag=indexPath.row;
```

Where inside a table cell there is a button `nav`

---

#### Then here is how I navigated to the `pageView`

```
-(void)naviguate:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         
                         [_tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 569, _tableView.frame.size.width, _tableView.frame.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"link" sender:self];
                     }];
    
}
```

Where `link` is the seague identifier

---

#### And this is how I have tried to share it

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    UIButton *theButton=(UIButton *)sender;
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"link"])
    { 
         NSLog(names[theButton.tag]);
         controller.name.text = names[theButton.tag];
    }
}
```

where `name` is a label inside `pageView`

---

But I am getting the error:

```
-[ImagesTableViewController tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

and nothing is being logged how come? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is saying that the `ImagesTableViewController` does not have a `tag` method, i.e., the `sender` in `prepareForSegue` is `ImagesTableViewController` which does not have a `tag` method (or property). However, the implementation of `prepareForSegue` assumes `sender` is a `UIButton` which does have a `tag` method, and thus your code compiles without an error.

Comment: So what should I change it to sorry?

Comment: @Maximilian Please read tag descriptions before applying them to your questions. You tend to use the [iphone] tag needlessly in all of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the control (label) property from the `imageViewController`, instead you want to pass the a `NSString` to this new instance of the pageView.

Once the segue is performed, set the label text in `viewDidLoad`

Add a property to the `pageView.h`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *blogName;
```

change the segue code

```
controller.name.text = names[theButton.tag];
```

to

```
 controller.blogName = names[tag];
```

in Page `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.name.text = _blogName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To carry @bobnoble 's explanation a little further:

In your `naviguate` method, you call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"link" sender:self];
```

Note that you pass "self" as the sender. That means that in prepareForSegue, the sender parameter will contain the current view controller.

If your `naviguate` method is an IBAction, as suggested by the fact that it has a sender parameter, why not change it like this:

```
-(IBAction) naviguate:(id)sender 
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
    delay:0
    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
    animations:^
    {
      [_tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 569, _tableView.frame.size.width, 
      _tableView.frame.size.height)];
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"link" sender: sender]; //Changed to pass sender
    }
  ];
}
```

That way you pass on the sender from your action method to the seque.

I would still change your prepareForSegue method to make sure that the sender responds to the "tag" selector before trying to get a tag value from it:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
  UIButton *theButton=(UIButton *)sender;
  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"link"])
  { 
    int tag = -1
    if (![theButton respondsToSelector: @selector(tag)])
      NSLog(@"Sender does not respond to 'tag'!");
    else
    {
      int tag = theButton.tag;

      NSLog(names[tag]);
      controller.name.text = names[theButton.tag];
    }
   }
}
```